# How to prevent automatic touchpad re-activation?

Tags: touchpad, xinput

I'm using the trackpoint of my Lenovo laptop and I'm quite happy with it. What is annoying, is having the touchpad activated at the same time.

Easy? Just disable the touchpad? Sure! I used to disable it via the system settings GUI, but for some reason this has no effect any more. Therefore I do deactivation now in the shell with **xinput set-prop xx "Device Enabled" 0**, found on this board.

Whether I use this command or the formerly working GUI method: After some time (definitely not after reboot) the touchpad is re-activated without any such command from my side!

Why?
And how can I prevent the system from doing this?
And how can I make the GUI method working again?